# Don't give us static about deleting [dynamic]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[dynamic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) is meaningless. Seems like it mostly attracts Excel-related question for some reason. There are also some questions on random topics, like folder binding, task scheduler, DDNS, dynamically extending VHDs, partitioning... it's just one moderately big mess.

<sub>Punny title courtesy of @fixer1234.</sub>